# Given that $P_1(x)=x^2-2$ and $P_j(x)=P_1(P_{j-1}(x))$ then prove that the roots of $P_n(x)=x$ are real and distinct

Tags: polynomials

I went on using induction

$P_1(x)=x$ and $P_2(x)=x$ have real and distinct roots

Assume that $P_{k-1}(x)-x=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)...(x-\alpha_t)$ has real and distinct roots

Then  $P_k(x)-x=P_1(P_{k-1}(x))-x =(x-\alpha_1)^2 (x-\alpha_2)^2 ...(x-\alpha_t)^2-2-x =0$

What to do next ? I tried factoring but no use.Any help??

Comment: Note that if $x=2\cos t$, then $P_1(x)=2\cos 2t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$P_1(x):=x^2-2$$

and

$$Q(x):=\frac14 x+\frac12  \ \text{and} \  L(x):=4x(1-x) \ \text{for} \ x \in [0,1]\tag{0}$$

where $L$ is known as (a version of) the [**logistic map**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map).

It is easy to show that :

$$P_1=Q \circ L \circ Q^{-1} \tag{1}$$

(one says that $P_1$ and $Q$ are conjugated).

where $\circ$ is the symbol for function composition. Let :

$$P_1^{[n]}:=\underbrace{P_1 \circ P_1 \circ \cdots P_1}_{n \ \text{times} \ P_1}$$

Using (1), one has :

$$P_1^{[n]}=Q \circ L^{[n]} \circ Q^{-1} \tag{2}$$

Therefore, your equation $P_1^{[n]}(x)=x$ is equivalent to $L^{[n]}(u)=u$ and this equation has $2^n$ real solutions. See for that :

- the explanation of @Andrew D. Huang [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1593336)
- or an almost explicit solution using the (bijective) change of variables

$$x=\sin^2 t \ \text{for} \ t \in [0,\pi/2]$$ that I give now :

Using (0) and a classical trigonometry formula : $$L(x)=L(\sin^2 t)=4 \sin^2 t (1 - \sin^2 t)=(2 \sin t \cos t)^2$$

i.e.,

$$L(\sin^2 t)=\sin(2t)^2\tag{3}$$

Therefore, setting

$$R(t):=\sin^2 (t) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ D(t):=2t,$$

relationship (3) can be written :

$$L \circ R = R \circ D \ \ \iff \ \ L= R \circ D \circ R^{-1}$$

i.e., once again a conjugation relationship giving : 
$$L^{[n]}=R \circ D^{[n]} \circ R^{-1}\tag{4}$$

Remark : $D^{[n]}(u)=2^n u.$

Thus, combining (4) and (2), one obtains :

$$P_1^{[n]}=(Q \circ R) \circ D^{[n]} \circ (Q \circ R)^{-1} \tag{5}$$

One finds back in this way the "almost explicit" solutions given in this interesting [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3083063) I just discovered now !

See as well the answer of EditPiAf [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3189990).